# What punishments do VTM and its supplements recommend a Prince dispense to his disobedient subjects?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

The Masquerade material gives us the Traditions as the law of the Camarilla which a Prince upholds in their domain. These are, in short:

- Keep the Masquerade.
- Some people here have territory, trespass at your own discretion.
- Don't create more vampires without permission.
- If you do create more vampires with permission, you are responsible for them until they grow up.
- Introduce yourself if you are new.
- Thou shalt not kill, unless you are old enough to actually issue kills which you probably aren't.

Together with the rules, especially the last one, the Blood Hunt is usually mentioned, an official call for the destruction of a certain individual, generally in response to that individual's breaking of one or more laws. As the Blood Hunt, if executed, ends in Final Death it is a sure way to get rid of the criminal, yet it might seem a bit harsh for some crimes and/or Princes.

**Which ways do *VTM* and/or available supplements propose to punish a vampire, other than the Blood Hunt?**

I'm also open for punishments "creative" Princes, Anarchs or the Sabbat might issue (they do have their own version, called the Wild Hunt, if I remember correctly) or which might be mentioned in novels and other material, as long as it is canon. For example, I seem to remember that in one of the clan novels somebody keeps a bunch of vampires held under a bridge - they are unable to leave and mostly protected from the sun during the day, but not completely, resulting in them being slowly roasted into torpor.

(This question is a redraft of my [previous one about punishments](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101956/how-to-punish-a-vampire) which was too broad, thus the concentration on answers stemming from official material here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Prince is not Sabbat or Anarchs. He is *the* Camarilla. What he can do:

1. Issue a Blood Hunt
2. Take away a good Status, or give a bad Status
3. Make him owe the Price a favour. Or several favours.

These are just those that are officially listed. I have seen all of it in LARP, worked perfectly -- because it is supposed to work and tested to work.

Good luck. :)

Comment: I think exiling someone (thus something in between status and blood hunt) is also possible. And then issuing a blood hunt if the poor idiot tries to come back.  Additionally isn't also staking someone (not for the sun, but as punishment to be shown as decoration for some time) also a punishment dished out a few times (could be the later was part of some fanfiction I read about masquerade and thus not happneing in any book)

Comment: Thanks. : ) Status and favours are so central, but I did not think of them, yet (probably because the SCs haven't even managed to get some). 

That said, afaik Princes are but a part of the Camarilla, having influences above and below them. Yet, in their city they are the law, so if they feel inspired by a sect's or individual's actions they are well capable to deploy the same on their citizens. Granted, if that is not compliant to Camarilla customs _and_ somebody more powerful finds out _and_ has an interest in stopping it, this might become problematic ...

Comment: @Thomas E As far as I understand, the Blood Hunt is sort of an exilation in many cases, as/if the culprit is given a grace period to handle their affairs and leave town before the hunt officially starts. Staking someone is sure to at least enervate them - putting them on display is something I hadn't thought of. Definitely an experience you would not want to repeat.

Comment: @ethan tbh I never heard of a grace period for a blood hunt. As far as I always heard and read its a death penalty by itself and usually you don't give a grace period there as its not only a death penalty for the perpetrator but also an exemple (a nice reminder) for all those who think that the prince in question is not harsh enough.

Comment: @ThomasE. Have neither ever heard of the grace period, but seems like a good idea. Plus, Blood Hunt is only for one place, not for everywhere, so you can treat it as exilation.

Answer (score 1):

I have read of punishments including the killing of childer/ghouls, taking away one's domain and the Blood Oath (or 2 steps towards it anywya).  Don't forget Domination.  Exile backed up by domination ("you will never return to New Orleans") can be wicked.  The exile/domination was in one of White Wolf's fictional books.